# How to pass address of specific element in array of strings form called function to another function

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

This is my sample program

```
void first_call();
void second_call();
int main()
{
char *str[]={"We will teach you how to...",
              "Move a mountain",
              "Level a building",
              "Erase the past",
              "Make a million",
              "...all through C!"};
first_call(str);

return 0;
}
```

str is passed to "first_call()"
now i want print character 'i' from "mountain" in second string .

```
void first_call(char **str)
{

printf("%s",str[1]); //to print second string,working

printf("%c",*(&str[1]+13));  //to print 'i' form second string
                             //but not working

second_call(&(&str[1]+13));  //to pass address of address of element of string
                              //not working,and giving error
}
```

I also want to pass address of that specific in second_call().

```
void second_call(char ***s_element)
{
printf("\n%c",**s_element);  //not working
}
```

how Should i do it.

Comment: Arrays starts with `0` in C. To print `i` character from second string use: `printf("%c", *(str[1] + 14)`.

Comment: I highly doubt `printf("%s" str[2]);` prints the string you want

Comment: @TheophileDano why wouldn't? It prints third string in array (*Level a building*)

Comment: @tilz0R yes, but it doesn't print the one woth `Mountain`. (the one the OP is looking to work with afaik)

Comment: oh so sorry , my mistake. but it still not working.  Edited

Comment: @TheophileDano that's true. but looks like OPs second string is answer to *We will teach you...* which is the `0` element in array.

Comment: And using `str[2] + 13` to access the `'i'` in the second string is giving out `'d'` from the third string. (luckily it's no the i otherwise the OP would find a bug soon)

Comment: strchr(str[1], 'i');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
printf("%c",*(&str[1]+13));
```

to this:

```
printf("%c", *(str[1] + 13));
```